# php cookies are not setting?

Tags: php, cookies

```
<?php
if (!isset($_COOKIE['firsttime']))
{
setcookie("firsttime", "no", time()+1500); 
 ?>

 <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span4 center">
        </div>
            <div class="span4 center">
            <div style="">
                    <div class="alert alert-info">
                            <button type="button"     href="<?php setcookie("firsttime", "no", time()+1500); ?>" class="close" data-   dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
                            <strong>Welkom</strong> <br   />Dit is je eerste bezoek op wijktoernooi.nl ! <br /> Wil je je direct registreren? Klik hier!
                    </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="span4 center">
        </div>

    </div>
<?php
}
 else
{
// do or show nada !
}
?>
```

Based upon code above if no cookie is set it should set cookie firsstime and show the alert box

But it doesnt....when i reload the page i still see the alert box, where am i making a mistake?

Comment: Turn on error reporting `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` I am betting that you have HTML output before the `setcookie()` call, causing `Headers already sent` errors, since you are sending `<div>`s out of nowhere

Comment: Remove setcookie from your href="" code (must be used before sending html content). Your code works on my server. your browser have cookie enabled ? What is your development environment ?

Comment: Use `setcookie("firsttime", "no", time()+1500, '/');` to make sure it's set for the whole domain - I doubt this will fix your particular problem, but it might help on other pages.

Comment: You can use firecookie plugin to check what is happening with the cookies. Most probably it is what @Michael just said.

Comment: use firefox firebug to view the cookies set for your domain, if there is no key with the name 'fisrttime' means something is wrong with setting up the cookies. or simlpy try to debug using print $_COOKIE and exit etc.

Comment: you can also try to increase the cookie life, some it causes trouble due to different timezones

Answer (score 2):

**You cannot send output before setting cookies.** You need to understand **HTTP**.
So do this test: `var_dump(headers_sent());` before you try to set a cookie.
If headers are sent, you're doing it wrong.

**`href="<?php setcookie(...); ?>"` is by far the most creative use of `PHP` ever**. PHP prints stuff. It does not react to `HTML/DOM/JS` events. It takes input and produces output. That's all it does.

I cannot give you any code that works here as you don't have the understanding required to make heads or tail of it. So figure out **`HTTP`** *(client/browser & server/php communication)*, **`cookies`** and only then will you be able to fix this and do it right in the future.